# JavaScript Date Manipulation (Insert Current Time in old Date)

Tags: javascript, date

I want to ask a question. Can we insert current Time in old Date?

Like this is a old date "Fri Nov 19 2021 **00:00:00** GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)" and I want to convert it to something like this "Fri Nov 19 2021 **(current Time right now)** GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean convert it? The format looks the same.

Comment: In former string time is 00:00:00 and I want current Time in place of 00:00:00

Comment: So you would like the date to stay the same but use the current time?

Comment: Yeah. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the setHours method, as in the following example:

```
const saveTime = new Date();
console.log(saveTime);
Tue Nov 23 2021 06:24:29 GMT-0500 (Cuba Standard Time)
saveTime.setHours(20,35,43)
console.log(saveTime);
Tue Nov 23 2021 20:35:43 GMT-0500 (Cuba Standard Time)
```

Comment: No, new Date().getTime() also returns back current date with time. I have to use current Time which is right now and set it to old Date.

Comment: I have did it like this.
 let date, newDate;
 date = new Date(endTime); // Any old Date
 newDate = new Date();
 const hours = newDate.getHours();
 const mins = newDate.getMinutes();
 date.setHours(hours);
 date.setMinutes(mins);
 const endDate2 = new Date(date).getTime();

Comment: You're right, now I'm looking for a solution to what you want